# Control Views Bulk Operation messages?

Tags: views

For my purposes I don't need these types of messages:

```
2 rows processed in about 261 ms:
Performed Email Reviewers on user joren1.
Performed Email Reviewers on user joren5.
```

I don't want to hide messages in general. Is there a way to specifically target messages from this module, or specific messages at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can uncheck "Display processing result" in the VBO settings (in the edit view UI).

VBO for D7 stopped generating that many messages in latest -devs (after beta1). It now only shows one message: "Performed $operation on $count items."

That is something that should be backported to D6, there's an [open issue](http://drupal.org/node/1233700) for it.
In general, you can't affect those, the module is just calling `drupal_set_message` (usually in `_views_bulk_operations_execute_finished()`).

Answer (score 2):

As general solution that works independently from the module that writes the messages you want to see, you can override [theme_status_messages()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_status_messages/7), and filter out the messages you don't want appearing.

You need to implement [hook_theme_registry_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7) in a module, using code similar to the following one:

```
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  if (isset($theme_registry['status_messages'])) {
    $theme_registry['status_messages']['function'] = 'theme_mymodule_status_messages';
  }
}
```

`theme_mymodule_status_messages()` is the function that the module implements to filter out the messages that would appear to the user, and that modules add through `drupal_set_message()`.

In the case of the Views Bulk Operations, it is enough to update the module to the latest version, but if you need to control the messages output from modules, you can implement the functions I described here.

Comment: I marked Bojan's as the answer because it addresses my specific problem most easily, but this code is going to come in handy in-future, thanks.

Comment: Hmmm can you elaborate a bit on this? What parameters does the function take? How can I determine the correct key from the theme_registry? The module that produces the messages I wish to filter isn't in the list.

Comment: The code you should write for `theme_mymodule_status_messages()` is similar to the code used by [theme_status_messages()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_status_messages/7); the difference is that you first check that the content of the `$message` variable (or `$messages[0]`) is the message you want to filter out; if it is the message you want to filter out, then you don't output it.

Comment: Question? when i do block multiple user at a time through views bulk operation module in views  .... i get this success message (Performed Block current user on 2 items.).. but i want to sucess message like this (user1 and user2 sucessfully blocked), please suggest me. how can i do this